# Reading a paragraph in c language

Tags: c

```
#include<Stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    char a[100];
    clrscr();
    printf("enter a paragraph\n");
    scanf("%s",a);
    printf("%s",a);
    getch();
}
```

output:
enter a paragraph
my name is vasanth
my

how do I read the entire line "my name is vasanth" using scanf function?

Comment: `scanf`stops reading at the first white space, use `fgets` and skip the trailling `\n`

Comment: use only scanf statement.

Comment: `#include<Stdio.h>` --> `#include <stdio.h>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `scanf` function:

```
scanf("%99[^\n]", a);
```

Where `%[^\n]` is a character set specifier that allows all characters except newlines, and `%99[^\n]` limits the match to at most 99 characters (since `a` has space for that many characters plus the null terminator).

Alternatively, you can use

```
fgets(a, 100, stdin);
```

This is arguably more common, but be aware that it leaves the newline at the end intact.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked multiple times and the answer to this is

Use

```
fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin);
size_t n = strlen(a);
if(n>0 && a[n-1] == '\n')
a[n-1] = '\0';
```

If you want to use scanf() only then you need to do

```
scanf("%99[^\n]",a);
```

Where [^\n] tells read until newline character is encountered and 99 makes sure that there is not buffer overflow. Still `fgets()` is a good option to read strings compared to `scanf()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **fgets**  as below

```
fgets (a, 100, stdin);
```

Comment: I know gets or fgets functions reads the blank spaces also, please use only scanf function.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `fgets( )` function to read a line of text.

`fgets(str , 100 , stdin);`

You can also use gets( ) function if your string is small since this funtion has no buffer overflow protection.

`gets(str)`

U can also use `scanf` to do this as others have mentioned.

Comment: This answer is harmful: `gets` is a broken function that has no buffer overflow protection. It has been removed from the latest C standard. It should be never used.

Comment: ya i have fixed it in the answer